# how pass date range parameter to request historical info from oanda api and put it in the highcharts?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetch data using http://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/history?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=midpoint&granularity=W&start=1351728000000&end=1368144000000

to get data in between to dates but it showing:

```
{
    "code" : 45,
    "message" : "Invalid timestamp: [start] parameter",
    "moreInfo" : "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/"
}
```

What I did wrong? I'm using this reference to set sart and end date. http://developer.oanda.com/docs/v1/rates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs you posted, you should be using RFC3339 format, not timestamp:

> start:
>
> Optional
>
> The start timestamp for the range of candles requested. Must be specified in RFC3339 format.

Examples:

```
2002-10-02T15:00:00Z
2012-11-01T00:00:00Z
2013-05-01T00:00:00Z
```

And proper encoded URI:

```
http://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/history?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=midpoint&granularity=W&start=2012-11-01T00%3A00%3A00&end=2013-11-01T00%3A00%3A00
```

Comment: Ok, but the response data is not returning in between 2012-11-01 and 2013-11-01.its always returning response data from 2013-04-05 to 2013-10-25. I also changed the date range but still same data is returning.

Comment: Because they don't have date before 2013-04-03? When tried to get last 5000 days, without start&end then I get similar result: http://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/history?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=midpoint&granularity=D&count=5000

Comment: Of course, I may be wrong. I think you should ask their support directly, to confirm that.